# How to ensure the available port on each server in a group?

Tags: service, deployment, ip, port

I have some servers in a group. I need to start service programs on them dynamically and listen to same port.

But how can I make sure that the port is available on each server?
How does those management system programs do this?

Comment: you need different IPs or domains then. domain1:80 for service program 1 and domain2:80 for service program 2

Answer (score 0):

Each combination of domain and port can be served only once in a network.
It's possible to map several domains on one IP.

If several services shall be available for one port, a new domain for each service has to be created. Using separate IPs instead of domains for each service is possible too.

Question is if the services really need this server-access to the port, or if a client-access is enough. Client-access means that a service just is calling a service like a website to view the output, Server-Access means that the the service want to serve on that domain:port - combination and therefore is colluding with other servers that want to listen / serve the same combination. Usually services take care of this and you can't start a second for a domain:port-combination after having started another one already.

Comment: Actually I have a load balancer to dispatch the request. And either I have the haproxy to dispatch request to different ip:port or I make sure services can listen on the same port (no other processes hold the port on services) but different ip. I wonder if I can go by the second method?

Comment: Sure you can let serve a service (assume a web-server) on different ports.
The common ports 80 and 443 are served for web-access and for anything else you can adjust 8080, 8081, 8082, etc. Take care that the ports are not needed otherwise, i.e. by tomcat-server.
With IPs / Domains you can do it the same, if you use IPs like 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255 it's clear they are only for internal usage.
Maybe you can give an example for a service, for an impression.

Comment: Perhaps I describe the  question vaguely, so I ask another, please refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233499/how-to-bind-same-port-on-a-different-machines

Comment: Ok, I see the problem is a bit different than I understood. Nevertheless an example for a service would be interesting.